# Can't get access token from Instagram api - Bad Request

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

We currently use the Instagram API in our application and we have a problem connecting an Instagram account (all others are working well)

Here is the url called :

https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https://dashthis.com/app/admin/Authorizations/Complete&response_type=code

We are able to get a code after the client login, but we can't exchange it for an access token due to the Bad Request error where calling this URL:

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token

Here is the details of what we got :

{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{ Pragma: no-cache Vary: Cookie Vary: Accept-Language Connection: keep-alive Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache, private Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2017 01:03:53 GMT Set-Cookie: csrftoken=Z35VDHdjhFdPAeGxuwy3tVYNKucfF3kk; expires=Wed, 21-Feb-2018 01:03:53 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; Secure Content-Length: 83 Content-Language: en Content-Type: application/json Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT }}

That's the only account having this issue. It's working great for all our other clients. We even checked directly in the client account to see if there was some setting, but couldn't find any reason why we would get a Bad Request error.

Have you an idea ?

Thanks.